# "xcrun xctrace list devices" command only lists some of the connected devices

Tags: macos, xcode

I upgraded macOS system version to 14.3.1, and also upgraded Xcode version to 13.4.1.

When I use `xcrun xctrace list devices` in order to list all devices connected to my Mac mini, only two devices display on terminal UI. However, there are eight devices on Mac mini.

I try `idevice_id -l" and "ios-deploy -c` command, it works fine.

I have tried restarting the Mac mini, and reconnected devices.

Comment: macOS 14.3.1 isn't available yet, not even in beta. Do you mean macOS 13.4.1 and Xcode 14.3.1?